# use Linq to form a relationship where none exists in the database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been using the .Net Core Linq expressions `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` to great success with my Entity Framework Core project.

However, I need to combine 2 models that are not in any type of relationship in the database.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
  SELECT * FROM selectedEnzymes se
  LEFT JOIN enzymeDefinitions ed ON se.selectedEnzymeID = ed.selectedEnzymeID
  WHERE se.ecosystemID = 7
```

*selectedEnzymes* and *enzymeDefinitions* are both models.

But there is no relationship between them even though they both contained a *selectedEnzymeID*.  In the database, there is no key.

So I was wondering, is there a way to use Linq to combine two models in such a way if no relationship exists?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is, should there be a foreign key? It looks like that to me.

Comment: Short answer, no you don't need a foreign key to create a relationship in EF. But you don't do it with LINQ. You need to configure you model first using the Fluent API

Comment: @insane_developer I agree but unfortunately the database cannot be modified. :(

Comment: @Michael Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by configuring my model.  I do have my model, but I would I do it with Fluent?  thanks

Comment: Fluent or annotations. The point is you can tell EF that there is a relationship even if there's no FK in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ Join and Select as you do in SQL.

Starting with something like this as models and list of both Classes:

```
public class SelectedEnzymes
{
    public int SelectedEnzymeId { get; set; }
    public int EcosystemId { get; set; }
    public string OtherPropertySelectedEnzymes { get; set; }
}

public class EnzymeDefinitions
{
    public int SelectedEnzymeId { get; set; }
    public string OtherPropertyEnzymeDefinitions { get; set; }
}

List<SelectedEnzymes> selectedEnzymesList = new List<SelectedEnzymes>();
List<EnzymeDefinitions> enzymeDefinitionList = new List<EnzymeDefinitions>();
```

You are able to do something like this:

```
var query = selectedEnzymesList // table in the "FROM" 
   .Join(enzymeDefinitionList, // the inner join table
      selected => selected.SelectedEnzymeId, // set the First Table Join parameter key
      definition => definition.SelectedEnzymeId, // set the Secont Table Join parameter key
      (selected, definition) => new { SelectedEnzyme = selected, EnzymeDefinition = definition }) // selection -> here you can create any kind of dynamic object or map it to a different model
   .Where(selectAndDef => selectAndDef.SelectedEnzyme.EcosystemId == 7);    // where statement
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to return something like: `.Select(x => new EnzymeObject { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name ... etc })`
                           .ToListAsync();

Answer (score 1):

> So I was wondering, is there a way to use Linq to combine two models
> in such a way if no relationship exists?

In fact, this is similar to the method of obtaining two related tables.

You can directly use the following linq to achieve:

```
 var data = (from se in _context.SelectedEnzymes
                        join ed in _context.EnzymeDefinitions
                        on se.SelectedEnzymeId equals ed.SelectedEnzymeId
                        where se.EcosystemId == 7
                        select new { se.Name,se.LocationId, ed.Name,ed.CountryId }).ToList();
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! But how would I select certain properties for the select statement?  Like `se.Name, se.LocationId, ed.Name, ed.CountryId` ?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, of course, just replace `select new {se, ed}` to what you want like `select new {se.Name,se.LocationId, ed.Name, ed.CountryId}`.I have modified my code.

Comment: what about this way? `Select(x => new EnzymeObject 
                           { ...
                            })`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, yes, you can do that. Just make sure the fields in `{ }` are the field name of `EnzymeObject ` class, or you can show me your EnzymeObject  class.